# example of a continuous and a bounded function which is not Lipschitz continuous

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

whether there exists any example of a continuous and a bounded function which is not Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: $$f(x) = \min \left\{ \sqrt{|x|} , 1 \right\}$$ is such a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$x \mapsto \sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ is such a function. If it were $M$-Lipschitz, then for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ with $x \neq y$,

$$\sqrt x + \sqrt y \ge \frac1M$$

Which is a contradiction.